# URLRequest load ownly when file is new, then fire NotificationType.CRITICAL

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

using AS3 and Flash CS5

I have a messageboard Adobe Air desktop App with a URLLoader making a URLRequest for a ".txt" file every 2 minutes. or however long I set the time to look. The App loads the txt file into a dynamic text field.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("https://my_text_file.txt"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var loadedText:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    myText_txt.htmlText = loadedText.data;
}
```

Is it possible to have the URLRequest load the file only if its new? not every time?

then when the "new" file has been loaded fire

```
mainWindow.notifyUser(NotificationType.CRITICAL)
```

so the user knows there is a new message?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("https://my_text_file.txt"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var loadedText:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    if(myText_txt.htmlText!=loadedText.data){
        myText_txt.htmlText = loadedText.data;
            mainWindow.notifyUser(NotificationType.CRITICAL) 
    }else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. when I publish file I get an error - Scene 1, Layer 'as text', Frame 1, Line 15 1120: Access of undefined property mainWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Since the application will still be running you should just compare the old text file to the new one to see if there have been any changes made.

Comment: how do I do that in AS3, new to to Actionscript3

Comment: You'll keep a reference to the old txt file by saving it to a local variable.  and then just compare it like in the other answer on page.

Comment: Would it be possible to you show me how the code would look? thanks in advance. I am a designer and this Actionscript 3 drives me nuts